# Is the following function of several variables concave?

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Suppose that $w_1,\dots,w_p\in(0,1)$ satisfy the condition $\sum_i w_i=1$, and let $$F(w_1,\dots,w_p) = \frac{1-\sum_i w_i^2}{\sum_i(1-w_i)^2 \left[\sum_i \frac{w_i}{1-w_i}\right]^2}.$$
Is function $F$ concave?